# How can I create and pass a variable to another query?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
UPDATE uye SET bakiye=bakiye+100 WHERE ID IN 
(SELECT uye FROM kupon WHERE ID IN 
( select c.kupon from kuponbahis c 
join bahis b on b.sonuc = c.secim and b.ID = c.bahis 
group by c.kupon 

having sum(c.bahis = 24) > 0 and count(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM kuponbahis WHERE kupon = c.kupon)))
```

This query works but instead of "100" i want to change it with inside variables like;

```
UPDATE uye SET bakiye=bakiye+VARIABLE WHERE ID IN 
(SELECT uye, VARIABLE FROM kupon WHERE ID IN 
( select c.kupon from kuponbahis c 
join bahis b on b.sonuc = c.secim and b.ID = c.bahis 
group by c.kupon
```

I can do it with a PHP code, but i want to put all the process to SQL directly.

(Note: Yes, my desired variable is inside of kupon table)

Comment: you can do by passing variable, so you can use stored procedure

Comment: Your request makes no sense.  The `IN` list should have only one column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you don't want a *variable*.  You want a column from the subquery.  In that case, use a `JOIN`:

```
UPDATE uye JOIN
       (SELECT k.*
        FROM kupon k
        WHERE k.ID IN (select c.kupon
                       from kuponbahis c join
                            bahis b
                            on b.sonuc = c.secim and b.ID = c.bahis 
                       group by c.kupon 
                       having sum(c.bahis = 24) > 0 and
                              count(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM kuponbahis WHERE kupon = c.kupon)
                   )
     ) k
     ON k.eye = uye.id
    SET bakiye=bakiye + k.VARIABLE;
```

Answer (score 1):

if you're trying to use stored procedure, you can declare and use variables:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE setBakiye 
(
   bakiyeEkle INT
) 
BEGIN 
    UPDATE uye SET bakiye=bakiye+bakiyeEkle WHERE ID IN 
    (SELECT uye FROM kupon WHERE ID IN 
    ( select c.kupon from kuponbahis c 
    join bahis b on b.sonuc = c.secim and b.ID = c.bahis 
    group by c.kupon 

    having sum(c.bahis = 24) > 0 and count(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM     kuponbahis WHERE kupon = c.kupon)))
END;
```